# Getting image rendering errors while sending it through C code using fread and send functions over tcp socket in a http response

Tags: c, image, http, sockets, binary

I am writing a simple web server as a personal project in c. The server can take in a static files path and then serve those static files. The approach I am using is working well for any `text/*` content-type but I am getting errors in the browser saying that the image contains errors.

Here is a snippet of the handler function that is responsible to send the response. The `else-if` block is responsible for sending static files.

```c
// thread function
void *client_handler(void *arg)
{
    client_server_t *client_server = arg;
    uint8_t recv_line[MAX_LINE + 1];
    uint8_t buff[MAX_LINE + 1];
    uint8_t req_string[3000];
    int n;
    size_t req_len = 0;

    memset(recv_line, 0, MAX_LINE);

    // print the request
    while ((n = recv(client_server->conn_fd, recv_line, MAX_LINE - 1, 0)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "\n%s\n\n%s", bin2hex(recv_line, n), recv_line);

        memcpy(req_string + req_len, recv_line, n);
        req_len += n;

        if (recv_line[n - 1] == '\n') break;

        memset(recv_line, 0, MAX_LINE);
    }

    if (n == 0)
        owl_println("Connection closed by client");
    else if (n < 0)
        err_n_die("read error");

    // get the http headers
    http_req_t *http_req = http_req_init((char *)req_string);
    owl_hashmap_t *routes_map = client_server->server->routes;
    owl_hashmap_t *http_status_map = client_server->server->http_status_map;

    http_res_t *http_res = http_res_init();

    http_route_t *route = owl_hashmap_get(routes_map, &(http_route_t){.uri = http_req->uri});

    // Date header indicates the data and time the response was generated
    char date_str[100];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *gmtime(&now);
    strftime(date_str, sizeof(date_str), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", &tm);

    if (route)
    {
        // After calling the handler, "http_res" will be populated
        char *res = route->handler(http_req, http_res);
        size_t res_len = strlen(res);

        // get the reason string from the status map
        status_code_with_reason_t *scr = owl_hashmap_get(http_status_map,
                                                         &(status_code_with_reason_t){.code = http_res->status_code});
        if (!scr) err_n_die("%d http status is not supported by the server.", http_res->status_code);
        http_res->reason = scr->reason;

        // format headers to send in the response
        char headers[MAX_HEADER_LEN] = "";
        size_t headers_len = 0;
        void *item;
        size_t iter = 0;
        while (owl_hashmap_iter(http_res->headers, &iter, &item))
        {
            const header_t *header = item;
            headers_len += snprintf(headers + headers_len, sizeof(headers) - headers_len,
                                    "%s: %s\r\n", header->name, header->value);
        }
        // format the response string
        char chunk[BUFF_SIZE];
        size_t bytes_sent = 0;
        size_t bytes_remaining = res_len;
        snprintf((char *)buff, sizeof(buff),
                 "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %zu\r\nDate: %s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n",
                 http_res->status_code, http_res->reason, http_res->content_type, res_len, date_str, headers);
        headers_len = strlen((char *)buff);
        if (send(client_server->conn_fd, (char *)buff, headers_len, 0) < 0)
            err_n_die("Error while sending headers");

        while (bytes_remaining > 0)
        {
            size_t bytes_to_send = MIN(BUFF_SIZE, bytes_remaining);
            memcpy(chunk, res + bytes_sent, bytes_to_send);
            if (send(client_server->conn_fd, chunk, bytes_to_send, 0) < 0)
            {
                err_n_die("Error while sending response chunk");
            }
            bytes_sent += bytes_to_send;
            bytes_remaining -= bytes_to_send;
        }

        // header_t *header = owl_hashmap_get(http_req->headers, &(header_t){.name = "Connection"});
    }
    else if (server->num_registered_file_paths > 0)
    {
        char filepath[MAX_PATH_LEN];
        int found = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < server->num_registered_file_paths; i++)
        {
            snprintf(filepath, MAX_PATH_LEN, "%s%s", client_server->server->static_files_path[i], http_req->uri);

            if (access(filepath, F_OK) == 0)
            {
                owl_println("filepath: %s", filepath);
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) goto send404;

        FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "rb");
        if (!fp) goto send404;

        // get the file size
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fsize = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

        char *content_type = "text/plain";
        char *ext = strrchr(filepath, '.');
        if (ext)
        {
            if (strcmp(ext, ".html") == 0)
                content_type = "text/html";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".css") == 0)
                content_type = "text/css";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".js") == 0)
                content_type = "text/javascript";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".png") == 0)
                content_type = "image/png";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".jpg") == 0 || strcmp(ext, ".jpeg") == 0)
                content_type = "image/jpeg";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".gif") == 0)
                content_type = "image/gif";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".svg") == 0)
                content_type = "image/svg+xml";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".ico") == 0)
                content_type = "image/x-icon";
            else if (strcmp(ext, ".avif") == 0)
                content_type = "image/avif";
        }

        // format headers to send in the response
        char headers[MAX_HEADER_LEN] = "";
        size_t headers_len = 0;
        void *item;
        size_t iter = 0;
        while (owl_hashmap_iter(http_res->headers, &iter, &item))
        {
            const header_t *header = item;
            headers_len += snprintf(headers + headers_len, sizeof(headers) - headers_len,
                                    "%s: %s\r\n", header->name, header->value);
        }

        // format the response string for other content types
        snprintf((char *)buff, sizeof(buff),
                 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: %s\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %ld\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", date_str, content_type, fsize, headers);

        if (send(client_server->conn_fd, (char *)buff, strlen((char *)buff), 0) < 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            err_n_die("Error while sending");
        }

        // send the file in chunks
        char file_buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
        size_t bytes_read = 0;
        while (bytes_read < fsize)
        {
            size_t bytes_to_read = fsize - bytes_read;
            if (bytes_to_read > BUFF_SIZE)
                bytes_to_read = BUFF_SIZE;

            size_t result = fread(file_buffer, 1, bytes_to_read, fp);
            if (result == 0)
                break;

            if (send(client_server->conn_fd, file_buffer, result, 0) < 0)
            {
                fclose(fp);
                err_n_die("Error while sending");
            }

            bytes_read += result;
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of the network tab in firefox v112.0

[image: Image Error]

I've tried checking that the image is not corrupted, I am sending the necessary headers, the content-type is right, and it's working well for any `text/*` content type. I've tried it on the other browsers

Let me know if something is not clear in the question. The full source code can be found at: https://github.com/rahulgpt/kraken

Modified code snippet according to @Steffen Ullrich answer.

```c
// send file in chunks
char file_buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
size_t bytes_read = 0;
while (bytes_read < fsize)
{
    size_t bytes_to_read = fsize - bytes_read;
    if (bytes_to_read > BUFF_SIZE)
        bytes_to_read = BUFF_SIZE;

    size_t result = fread(file_buffer, 1, bytes_to_read, fp);
    if (result == 0)
        break;

    size_t bytes_sent = 0;
    while (bytes_sent < result)
    {
        ssize_t sent = send(client_server->conn_fd, file_buffer + bytes_sent, result - bytes_sent, 0);
        if (sent == -1)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            err_n_die("Error while sending");
        }
        bytes_sent += sent;
    }

    bytes_read += result;
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Get rid of your send loop and just call `send(client_server->conn_fd, file_buffer, result, 0)`, checking it for errors of course. If you're not in non-blocking mode it can't do a short send, contrary to the answer below.

Comment: @user207421 I tried sending the whole file in one go. I increased the file_buffer size so that it can fit image `size_t result = fread(file_buffer, 1, fsize, fp)`, and I sent the entire thing using the send function. I think in case of images you have to send the headers first then the body. So technically there are two send calls, first one sends the headers and the next one sends the file. As @SteffenUllrich suggested, send can return less no. of bytes than we actually intended to send. So I checked it, it's sending the entire thing but still getting the same error.

Comment: I also looked at the network trace through Wireshark and added up the TCP segment length. It was exactly the same size as the image and headers. Additionally, all the ACKs were received and the connection was closed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had three CRLF sequences between the last header and the body instead of two.

```c
while (owl_hashmap_iter(http_res->headers, &iter, &item))
{
    const header_t *header = item;
    headers_len += snprintf(headers + headers_len, sizeof(headers) - headers_len,
                                    "%s: %s\r\n", header->name, header->value);
}
```

According to this, the last header will have a trailing CRLF.

```c
 // format the response string for other content types
snprintf((char *)buff, sizeof(buff),
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: %s\r\nContent-Type: %s\r\nContent-Length: %ld\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", date_str, content_type, fsize, headers);
```

But I was adding another two CRLF sequences. Removing one of those fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (send(client_server->conn_fd, file_buffer, result, 0) < 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            err_n_die("Error while sending");
        }

        bytes_read += result;
```

This logic is wrong. `send` might send less then `result` bytes. How many bytes are actually sent is returned by `send`. While this might not be a problem with small data like HTML it will be a problem with larger data like images, which no longer fit fully into the sockets send buffer. In this case parts of the data will not be actually sent, resulting in corrupted data.

Comment: Hey @Steffen, thanks for answering. Yes I think the logic is flawed as it's not guaranteed that the whole chunk would be sent. So should I get the sent bytes (bytes_sent) from send and then send the rest of the result (i.e result - bytes_sent) again or should I send the whole chunk again.

Comment: I looked it up on the internet and I believe that the only scenario in which the send function might not be able to send the entire response is when the BUFF_SIZE is larger than the send buffer size. In my case, the BUFF_SIZE is 4096, and all other files are sent successfully, so I assume it is well within the send buffer size limit. However, I attempted to modify the code to consider the number of bytes sent, and I am still encountering this error.

Comment: @RHGPT: *" I believe that the only scenario in which the send function might not be able to send the entire response is when the BUFF_SIZE is larger than the send buffer size."* - no quite correct. It depends on the size which is still available in the socket buffer. Previous writes will decrease what is available, if the data cannot be sent fast enough to the peer. *" I attempted to modify the code to consider the number of bytes sent, and I am still encountering this error. "* - please provide the modified code, maybe it is wrong too.

Comment: I've added the modified code snippet according to your suggestion. Please let me know if the logic is still wrong.

Comment: @RHGPT: code snippet looks good to me. What kind of corruptions to you get exactly, i.e. please compare what you expect to be sent with what is already send on the wire (captured with Wireshark or others).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to look at the network trace through Wireshark. Though I don't really know how to use Wireshark, I am watching tutorials to learn it. I just wanted to make sure that the code is correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you're in non-blocking mode, `send()` will send the entire length requested, blocking while it can't (while the send buffer is full). The Posix specification requires this behaviour.

Comment: @user207421: Could you please show were exactly in POSIX it says that? Because from experience of writing lots of network code (granted, most of this non-blocking) I can say, that send on TCP connections (i.e. stream mode not datagram mode) regularly returns less then what was given as argument.